# javascript planeGeometry hide

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a wall of my house, which I'vre created from planeGeometries. I want to use the 'o' key to hide and make it visible again. 
The problem is, if I'm using `scene.remove(groundMesh6);` to hide it, I can't make it visible again.

my code:

```
var groundGeometry6 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
var groundMaterial6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff,
    wireframe: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var groundMesh6 = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry6, groundMaterial6);
groundMesh6.rotation.x = -1.0 * THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
groundMesh6.position.y= 80;
scene.add(groundMesh6);

//Hide the wall
 window.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
function handleKeyPress(event) {
    var char = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (char == 111) {
        scene.remove(groundMesh6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with groundMesh6.visible = true/false

Comment: It hides it, but doesn't appear with the same key.